# "Function0 is not a functional interface" error when passing java lambda to kotlin fun

Tags: java, kotlin

This is my kotlin code:

```
class Foo : Bar {
  override var onRefreshListener: (() -> Unit)? = null
  ...
}
```

And this is what I try to do in java:

```
class A {
  private Foo foo;
  private void onRefreshStarted() {}
  private void problem() {
    foo.setOnRefreshListener(this::onRefreshStarted);
    foo.setOnRefreshListener(() -> onRefreshStarted());
  }
}
```

In both cases in problem() I get the following error from Android Studio:

> Function0 is not a functional interface

How can I set the onRefreshListener from java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After fixing the kotlin lib's dependencies in the pom file, here are the 3 possible solutions I could figure out.

**1st solution**: No need for kotlin-stdlib in the java project:

In kotlin add:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface OnRefreshListener {
    fun onRefresh()
}
```

And change the interface from:

```
var onRefreshListener: (() -> Unit)?
```

to:

```
var onRefreshListener: OnRefreshListener?
```

and the invocations from:

```
onRefreshListener?.invoke()
```

to:

```
onRefreshListener?.onRefresh()
```

**2nd solution**: (Thanks to @hotkey) needs the kotlin-stdlib, no change in kotlin code. In java change:

```
foo.setOnRefreshListener(() -> onRefreshStarted());
```

to:

```
foo.setOnRefreshListener(() -> { onRefreshStarted(); return Unit.INSTANCE; });
```

**3rd solution**: needs kotlin-stdlib, no change in kotlin, change:

```
private void onRefreshStarted() {}
```

to:

```
private Unit onRefreshStarted() {...; return null;}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that it's exactly why you get that kind of error, but you can try to fix your code by passing a `Unit`-returning lambda instead of a lambda without a return value:

```
foo.setOnRefreshListener(() -> { onRefreshStarted(); return Unit.INSTANCE; });
```

Since the `Function0<T>` interface's `invoke()` returns `T`, when calling a Kotlin method accepting a `() -> Unit` from Java, you have to pass a lambda that returns `Unit`.

Comment: For some reason I can't see kotlin.Unit, see my update in the question

Comment: Do you have a dependency to `kotlin-stdlib` in the `dependencies { ... }` block in your `build.gradle`? E.g. `compile  "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.10"` Or it may be one of its variants ending with `-jre7`, `-jre8`, `-jdk7`, `-jdk8`.

Comment: You found the problem! My kotlin lib uses the maven-publish plugin and it doesn't add the dependencies to the pom file

Comment: not exactly, because in my case there are no dependencies at all in the pom file